# Wordpress + Cherry Framework. Режется заголовок в разделе "Портфолио"

Tags: wordpress

Здравствуйте. Есть сайт на Wordpress + Cherry Framework. В данного фрейморка есть возможность настраивать раздел "Портфолио", однако все заголовки записей режутся до 40 символов. Как это исправить? В настройках фрейморка не нашел.

Answer (score 2):

А все было достаточно просто.

\wp-content\themes\CherryFramework\filterable-portfolio-loop.php

```
<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php $title = the_title('','',FALSE); echo mb_substr($title, 0, 40);?></a></h3>
```